# Validate and alter the overridden variable in a subclass declaration

Tags: python

I have two classes as such:

```py
class A:
    var = 1


class B(A):
    var = 2
```

Now I want to *validate* and *alter* the assignment that occurs in the subclass `B` from class `A`. I know I can use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator to add *setters* and *getters*, something like this:

```py
class A:
    _var = 1

    
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var
    

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        self._var = value + 1


class B(A):
    _var = 2


b = B()
print(b.var) # 2
b.var = 3
print(b.var) # 4

a = A()
print(a.var) # 1
a.var = 4
print(a.var) # 5
```

But this only works for *assignments to instances* of `B` or `A`. I understand why it works this way; `_var` in subclass `B` overrides `_var` in class `A` and `b.var` finds the *getter* in class `A`, which returns the now-overridden value of `2`. I'm only wondering if it's possible to achieve something like this:

```py
class A:
    var = 1
    """ other code """


class B(A):
    var = 2


b = B()
print(b.var)
# prints 2, which makes sense.
# I need another value, modified based on 2.
```

I can modify class `A` however I wish, but I can't change class `B`, unless not possible.

I have to add that inheritance is important and needed here, because I need this working example:

```py
class A:
    var = 1
    """ other code """


class B(A):
    """ other code """


b = B()
print(b.var)
# prints 1, as expected and needed.
```

Comment: You need a metaclass.  Maybe try that and edit the question if you then have a more specific problem?

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you so much. I didn't know such thing existed.